# How can I get Forecast of Time Series with periods the right way?

Tags: r, time-series, hierarchical

I am starting with time series forecasting with `hts` package in R.

I've already got my data and applied `forecast()` function. Summary of my forecast is like (the numbers are sample):

```
Hierarchical Time Series                            
2 Levels                            
Number of nodes at each level: 1 8                          
Total number of series: 9                           
Number of observations in each historical series: 53                            
Number of forecasts per series: 12  

Top level series of forecasts:                          

    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul
2018                        107 239
2019    127 184 244 123 249     


    Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec     
2018                        107 239
2019    127 184 244 123 249
```

So, `hts` actually knows the periods that I am forecasting for, Jun 2018 and further (12 points).
But when I trying to get `bts` of my time series, I get only values, not periods. Is there a way to build a data frame with periods in `hts`?

The Decision that I have in my head:

1. transform bts into a matrix
2. transform matrix into a simple time
       series, starting with a known period.

But it does not seem best and can cause errors - we know our desired periods in `hts`, why don't get them at once?

Thank You for Your kindness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```r
library(hts)
#> Loading required package: forecast

fc <- forecast(htseg1)
fc
#> Hierarchical Time Series 
#> 3 Levels 
#> Number of nodes at each level: 1 2 5 
#> Total number of series: 8 
#> Number of observations in each historical series: 10 
#> Number of forecasts per series: 10 
#> Top level series of forecasts: 
#> Time Series:
#> Start = 2002 
#> End = 2011 
#> Frequency = 1 
#>  [1] 53.43685 53.78687 54.13689 54.48690 54.83692 55.18694 55.53696
#>  [8] 55.88698 56.23699 56.58701
fc$bts
#> Time Series:
#> Start = 2002 
#> End = 2011 
#> Frequency = 1 
#>             AA       AB       AC       BA       BB
#> 2002  9.286307 10.05677 10.47942 11.04014 12.57421
#> 2003  9.460299 10.10103 10.49552 11.05347 12.67655
#> 2004  9.634290 10.14528 10.51162 11.06681 12.77889
#> 2005  9.808281 10.18954 10.52772 11.08014 12.88122
#> 2006  9.982273 10.23379 10.54382 11.09348 12.98356
#> 2007 10.156264 10.27804 10.55993 11.10681 13.08590
#> 2008 10.330255 10.32230 10.57603 11.12014 13.18823
#> 2009 10.504247 10.36655 10.59213 11.13348 13.29057
#> 2010 10.678238 10.41081 10.60823 11.14681 13.39291
#> 2011 10.852229 10.45506 10.62433 11.16015 13.49525
```

<sup>Created on 2018-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

As you can see, the time series attributes are attached to the `bts` component of the forecasts. `bts` is a time series matrix of class `mts`.

Comment: Prof. Hyndman, thank You for Your answer and Your work.
But let me tell about my decision. I used bts component as You suggetsted, but to get the date I use specifically as.Date(as.yearmon(time(s.htsforecast$bts))